# Unable to reference javascript variable in java call

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

I'm trying to reference a javascript variable in a java call but unfortunately I get the error the variable (userURL) cannot be resolved. How can I reference the variable?

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ page import="java.net.*, org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI, org.owasp.esapi.Validator" %>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function validateForm()
{

    var userURL = "http://www.google.com";
    var isValidURL = <% ESAPI.validator().isValidInput("URLContext", userURL, "URL", 255, false); %>
    if (isValidURL) {
        alert("true");
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: Learn about the page life cycle.

Answer (score 4):

The `userURL` exists in the web browser.

The JSP code is run on the web server.

You cannot pass `userURL` from the browser to the server without making another HTTP request.

So you need to either move that validation code to the client side (Javascript), or post it to the server (form submission or Ajax).

Answer (score 0):

You can not reference JS variable in JSP srciptlet.
You should define JSP variable.

Answer (score 0):

For all intent, everything that isn't JSP code can be considered as dumb strings without any signification for the Java container. Which means your server doesn't know anything about the values of Javascript variables. The Javascript code is not executed at the same time as the Java code, but much later in the application lifecycle, and not on the server but on the client, i.e. the browser.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but you should look into Ajax calls, so you can pass information, for example variable values, from your client to your server by a specific call.